# How can I "Zoom In" and "Zoom Out" canvas.create_image() with canvas.scale()?

Tags: python, canvas, video-streaming, zooming, tkinter-canvas

I tried to zoom in and out with scale, however, it didn't work.

And I am going to do it with the "button" and "resize" function instead of an event, but it seems that I cannot resize it through the `create_image()` function?

Can anyone give me some suggestions for fixing the code below or a better way for achieving the "Zoom" function?

```
from tkinter import ttk
import cv2
from cv2 import cv2 
from PIL import ImageTk
from PIL import Image
import time
import pyautogui as pyat
import numpy as np
from sense_hat import SenseHat
import tkinter.font as tkFont
from math import *

 
baf_pixel = 0
input = False
class APP:#建立主視窗python3
    def __init__(self,window,video_source=0):
        self.input = False
        self.sense = SenseHat()
        self.pitch, self.roll, self.yaw = self.sense.get_orientation().values()
        self.window = window
        self.window.title('Relaskop_pi')
        self.window.geometry('800x480')
        self.window.attributes("-alpha",1)
        self.video_source = video_source
        self.cap = MyVideoCap(self.video_source)
        #create canvas that contain the camera
        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(self.window,width=525,height=480)
        self.canvas.place(x = 135,y = 0)   
        self.update()
        self.canvas.bind("<ButtonPress-1>", self.move_start)
        self.canvas.bind("<B1-Motion>", self.move_to)
        self.canvas.bind("<Button-4>", self.zoomMag)#Magnify
        self.canvas.bind("<Button-5>", self.zoomNarrow)#Narrow
        self.window.mainloop()
    
    #move to the position you want to check
    def move_start(self, event):
        self.canvas.scan_mark(event.x, event.y)

    def move_to(self, event):
        self.canvas.scan_dragto(event.x, event.y, gain = 1)
    
    # def zoomer(self,event):
    #     print('Welcome')
    #     if (event.delta > 0):
    #         self.canvas.scale("all", event.x, event.y, 1.1, 1.1)
    #     elif (event.delta < 0):
    #         self.canvas.scale("all", event.x, event.y, 0.9, 0.9)
    #     self.canvas.configure(scrollregion = self.canvas.bbox("all"))
    
    #zoom function
    def zoomNarrow(self, event):
        self.canvas.scale("all", event.x, event.y, 0.9, 0.9)
        self.canvas.configure(scrollregion = self.canvas.bbox("all"))
    
    def zoomMag(self, event):
        self.canvas.scale("all", event.x, event.y, 1.1, 1.1)
        self.canvas.configure(scrollregion = self.canvas.bbox("all"))
    
    #update
    def update(self):
        ret, frame = self.cap.get_frame()
        if ret == True:
            font_p = tkFont.Font(family = "Biaukai", size = 12)
            lab_p=tk.Label(self.window, text="pitch:"+ str(round(270-self.pitch, 2)), justify='left',width=12,height=2,font= font_p,bg='red',anchor='nw').place(x=0,y=173)#Angle-updown
            lab_r=tk.Label(self.window, text="roll:" + str(round(self.roll, 1)), justify='left',width='10',height='1',font=('Biaukai',14),bg='red',anchor='nw').place(x=0,y=202)#Angle-horizontal
            lab_y=tk.Label(self.window, text="yaw:" + str(round(self.yaw, 1)), justify='left',width='10',height='1',font=('Biaukai',14),bg='red',anchor='nw').place(x=0,y=231)#Angle-verticalturn
            self.pitch, self.roll, self.yaw = self.sense.get_orientation().values()
            if self.input == True:
                self.getBAF()
            img=Image.fromarray(frame)
            self.imgtk=ImageTk.PhotoImage(image=img)            
            self.canvas.create_image(0, 0, image = self.imgtk, anchor = tk.NW)

        self.window.after(15,self.update)

class MyVideoCap:
    def __init__(self, video_source=0):
    #open the video source
        self.cap=cv2.VideoCapture(video_source)
        if not self.cap.isOpened():
            raise ValueError("Unable to open video source", video_source)
    

    def get_frame(self):
        if self.cap.isOpened():
            ret, frame=self.cap.read()
            frame=cv2.flip(frame,1)
            if ret == True:
                return (ret, cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB))
            else:
                return (ret, None)
        else:
            return (ret, None)
    # Release the video source when the object is destroyed
    def __del__(self):
        if self.cap.isOpened():
            self.cap.release()
        
if __name__=="__main__":
    APP(tk.Tk())
```